# indexPath.row reload in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewController` with 3 rows, in the first indexPath (0) I want to add a `UIView`. When I launch the App it works but when I go into another controller and come back, the `UIView` is in the other rows. This is the code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let customCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(customCellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    customCell.nameLabel.text = "\(label2.text) \(materie[indexPath.row])"
    customCell.setupViews()
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        customCell.setupUIView()
        customCell.nameLabel.text = ""
    }

    return customCell
}
```

When I launch the app the screen is:

[image: launch screen app]

When I go into another controller and come back, the screen is:

[image: screen]

Comment: Try calling `reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: Why don't you create a customCell with your view inside of it ?

Comment: reloadData() doesn't work, I tried. How can I create multiple customCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the square blue is repeated in another cell is because the collectionView is reusing the same cell.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let customCell = ollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(customCellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    // HERE YOU HAVE TO RESET THE CELL TO DEFAULT VALUES
    // LIKE REMOVING THE BLUE SQUARE VIEW
    customCell.view2.removeFromSuperview()

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        customCell.setupUIView()
        customCell.nameLabel.text = ""
    } else {   
        customCell.nameLabel.text = "\(label2.text) \(materie[indexPath.row])"
        customCell.setupViews()
    }

    return customCell
}
```

Comment: @AndreaToso Did you remove the blue square view before to setup the view?

Comment: @AndreaToso The page is not found

Comment: @AndreaToso I edit my answer, I just add `customCell.view2.removeFromSuperview()` to remove the blue view (if this is the main problem). You must have to add the code on your question not on an answer

Comment: The code was too long for the comment. My problem is that I don't wanna remove the blue view, but I want the blue view only in the first row

Comment: @AndreaToso Ok, the blue view it will be removed (in case it exist on UI), then will be added if is the first row, if is not the first row it will not be added because `UICollectionView`s reuses the cells, that's the reason it appear twice when you return back